# Decimal arithmetics in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, rounding, ieee-754

The IEEE-754 norm define decimal arithmetics in order to avoid rounding errors when using base-ten floating point numbers (see for example [decimal64 on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal64_floating-point_format)). Is there a way to use this decimal arithmetics in C or C++?

Comment: Use a library. libgmp, mpfr, Boost Multiprecision

Comment: The C standard doesn't have explicit decimal floating point types, but [GCC provides this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Decimal-Float.html). There are multiple competing binary representations; I believe GCC fixes the representation on each supported platform.

Comment: The decimal formats defined in IEEE-754 do not avoid rounding errors. (Try, e.g., 10 / 3)

Comment: Wow — another one? I think this is 4th question asked on floating point number today

Comment: @KerrekSB and sehe:  You should make your comments answers IMO.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Not according to the tag history. Maybe they weren’t carefully tagged. But were these other questions about *decimal* floating point numbers?

Comment: @sehe MPFR is a **binary** floating-point multi-precision library, and cannot replace decimal floating-point for some applications, at any precision.

Comment: You could look at the Intel library, http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-decimal-floating-point-math-library/

Comment: @PascalCuoq thanks for straightening that out. You're right

Answer (score 4):

TR 24733 specifies decimal floating-point math for C++, based on IEEE-754. The TR means that it's a technical report, so it's not part of the C++ standard. GCC says they have a partial [implementation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.tr24733). There is currently a proposal in the works to add it to the C++ standard, but that's several years away at best.

Comment: +1, thanks Pete for your valuable contributions. It's really powerful to have committee members/designers on board of a QA site.